# Adicionar um if com 2 condições

Tags: delphi

Tenho as Seguintes variaveis declaradas:

```
n_var:= strtoint (En_var.Text);
n_raster := strtoint (En_raster.Text);
```

E gostaria que fizesse uma condição comparando os valores delas por exemplo:

```
if (En_var.Text = (inttostr(3)) and (En_raster.text = (inttostr(1))))  then
```

mas recebo a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> [dcc32 Error] Urecomendacao.pas(117): E2010 Incompatible types:
>   'string' and 'Boolean'

Se eu fizer normalmente sem o *AND* ele funciona, exemplo:

```
if (En_var.Text = (inttostr(3)))  then
```

Qual é a causa disso?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Estava sobrando um ) em sua comparação:

altere seu código para isso:

```
if (En_var.Text = inttostr(3)) and  (En_raster.text = inttostr(1)) then
```

Comment: Perfeito, erro de observação mesmo.
Pode me informar o por que do erro de conversão de str e boolean?

Comment: Pois podemos dizer que o compilador se "perdeu" ao executar sua instrução. E ele acabou comparando seu En_var.Text que é uma string com a condição após o and que estava retornando um boolean.
   Fico feliz em poder lhe ajudar. Se puder colocar como melhor resposta eu agradeço.

Comment: Claro, estou agudando o tempo.
Obrigado pela ajuda.